# How can I build and push an array to my mongoose embedded model from the same named inputs

Tags: mongoose, ejs

My model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var Trainschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date1: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    date2: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    trainnum: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    startplace: String,
    destination: String,
    vagons: [{
        numvag: String,
        date1: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        date2: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        seatcount: String,
        reserves: [{
            numreserve: String,
            numseats: String
        }]
    }],
    weeks: [String],
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
Trainschema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Train', Trainschema);
```

here is my view:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Create Train</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h3><a href="/trains">Train List</a></h3>
      <h1>Create New Vagon</h1>
      <form action="/trains/upd/<%= train._id%>" method="post">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Train Number</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="trainnum" value="<%= train.trainnum%>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>From</td>
              <td><input type="date" name="date1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>To</td>
              <td><input type="date" name="date2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Vagon number</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="numvag" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>seats</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="seats" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Reserve number</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="resnum" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Seat Reserve</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="seatres" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Reserve number</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="resnum" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Seat Reserve</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="seatres" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you see I'm going to send values from two pairs of same named inputs: resnum and seatres. How can I build an array of reserves from received inputs (resnum and seatres) and push that into Trainschema's reserves attribute?

It's a controller

```
trainController.updateTr = function(req, res) {
    var numseats = JSON.stringify(req.body.reserves);
    var vagon = {
        numvag: req.body.numvag,
        date1: req.body.date1,
        date2: req.body.date2,
        seatcount: req.body.seats,
        reserves: { ** how to
            push **
        }
    };

    Train.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $push: {
            "vagons": vagon
        }
    }, {
        safe: true,
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    }, function(err, train) {
        if (err) {
            res.render("../views/trains/edit", {
                train: req.body
            });
        }
        res.redirect("/trains/show/" + train._id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using same name for multiple fields gives an array with that name, with index matching the order.

Assuming `resnum` and `seatres` will be ensured to have same length, you can create `reserves` array with map function:

```
var reserves;
if(Array.isArray(req.body.reserves)){
    reserves = req.body.resnum.map(function(r, index) {
        return {
            numreserve: r,
            numseats: req.body.seatres[index]
        }
    })
}
else{
    reserves = [{
        numreserve: req.body.resnum, 
        numseats: req.body.seatres
    }];  //even it's a single object, this still needs to be put in array, given your schema
}

var vagon = {
    numvag: req.body.numvag,
    date1: req.body.date1,
    date2: req.body.date2,
    seatcount: req.body.seats,
    reserves: reserves
};
```

Comment: I have this error "TypeError: req.body.resnum.map is not a function" when I'm going to add one array to reserves

Comment: Check by `console.log(req.body)` to see what you're getting in `req.body.resnum`. This should be array for `map` to work

Comment: it's not array. Here is req.body:   {"trainnum":"011Ф","date1":"2017-06-08","date2":"2017-06-17","numvag":"0
1K","seats":"20","cntr":"1","resnum":"1","seatres":"1-20"}. What should I do?

Comment: It's probably because you're using one `resnum` field in form. You must use at least two fields with same name to have it appear as array.

Comment: I've figured out this problem by adding one more request paramater -"counter" which I get from hidden element in the view. counter parameter calculated by javascript on the client side and written to the value of hidden input element. After getting counter, I check that whether it equals to one or not. here is my code:

Comment: if (req.body.cntr==1) {
      var vagon={numvag:req.body.numvag, date1 :req.body.date1,
  date2: req.body.date2, seatcount: req.body.seats, reserves: {numreserve: req.body.resnum, numseats: req.body.seatres}};
  }else{
      var vagon={numvag:req.body.numvag, date1 :req.body.date1,
  date2: req.body.date2, seatcount: req.body.seats, reserves: req.body.resnum.map(function(r, index){

    return {
      numreserve: r,
      numseats: req.body.seatres[index]
    }
    
  })};

Comment: of course it's your answer!!! I just added this :  var vagon={numvag:req.body.numvag, date1 :req.body.date1, date2: req.body.date2, seatcount: req.body.seats, reserves: {numreserve: req.body.resnum, numseats: req.body.seatres}. I mean if counter is not equal to 1 then I create vagon object using your method